# MIUI : How to move data to external SD card for installed app in Xiomi devices

Tags: external-sd, miui

I have been trying to figure out how to transfer the data of the apps installed in my Xiomi note. It pretty clear in other android devices where we can go to the app settings and open the installed app and transfer the data to SD card by selecting move to SD card but this option is not available in MIUI.